# isNumber() on Integer throws error

Tags: groovy

Does this error mean I am calling `isNumber()` on a null value? I can't seem to understand it.

```
No signature of method: 
java.lang.Integer.isNumber() is applicable for argument types: () values: []. 

Stacktrace follows:
Message: No signature of method: 
java.lang.Integer.isNumber() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

Comment: Which part is confusing?

Comment: Why would you call isNumber() on an int or an Integer?  The method doesn't exist, but it isn't clear why you want to do that anyway.

Comment: I actually just realized that result is from calling the method on something that already is an Integer. I was doing that because I didn't know in advance that I will need to call it on something that may not necessarily be convertible to an Integer. I have now fixed it though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error mean: the class `java.lang.Integer` has no method `isNumber()`
The method `isNumber()` belongs to class `java.lang.String`. See the docs: http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#isNumber()

Maybe you are trying to do something like this:

```
123.isNumber() // will trow the error
```

while the correct is:

```
"123".isNumber()
```

Comment: codehaus url  is 404.

Answer (score 2):

`isNumber` is a method of `String`. You're calling it on an integer - http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#isNumber()

It wouldn't make sense to call `isNumber` on a number. You know it is already. You would want to call it on the string that might be represnting a number.

Here's how to reproduce in the groovy shell.

```
groovy:000> new Integer(5).isNumber()
ERROR groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:
No signature of method: java.lang.Integer.isNumber() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```